# VMware Workstation - Linux/gnome screen saver locking of guest and host

Tags: linux, vmware-workstation, screensaver, redhat-enterprise-linux

I've got some RHEL6 machines that run VMware Workstation 11 on them. The host and the guest are required to have a screensaver enable after 15min of inactivity that goes to a lock screen.

My users are angry and rightfully so. The guest screen saver will kick in on one monitor and they can enter a password and turn it off. The second that their mouse enters the host environment either through mouse movement to the host desktop/monitor or cntrl+alt it locks the screen.

I've read some articles saying it might be a design issue with how gnome-screensaver interacts with keyboard and mouse.

Has anyone found a way to make this work better?

Answer (score 2):

Set VMware to ungrab the keyboard and mouse shortly before the host screensaver will kick in.  E.g., add this to `/etc/vmware/config`:

```
mks.fullscreen.allowScreenSaver = "yes"
mks.windowed.allowScreenSaver = "yes"
mks.x.screenSaverTimeout = 890
```

See http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2054255

Comment: You might want to add some of the content from the linked post - generally folk dislike "link only answers", because the linked content can change / disappear, leaving a useless answer.